# What causes a lexical analysis error for eclipse in jsp EL validation?

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, jstl, el

I've got some EL code inside of a JSP tag. The line starts as follows:

```
<c:if test="${pageContext.request.serverName eq \'localhost\'}">
```

Eclipse throws up an error on this, saying:

> Unable to analyze EL expression due to lexical analysis error

I'm unsure what this even means. Is this an eclipse bug? Am I mixing EL and the JSTL tags incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do it without backslash:

```
${pageContext.request.serverName eq 'localhost'}
```

A JSP with that code:

```
${pageContext.request.serverName eq 'localhost'}
<c:if test="${pageContext.request.serverName eq 'localhost'}">faith</c:if>
```

renders "true faith" for me. What does "${pageContext.request.serverName}" show?

Comment: Now I get 'Type mismatch: cannot convert from boolean to String'. I'll test if it actually works without the backslash.

Comment: It does work, it's just odd that the eclipse parser gets confused. Perhaps a bug?